# How to find if a column value is undervalued or overvalued based on other column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So i'm trying to solve this `pandas` exercise. I got this data set of Real estate firm from Kaggle and the data frame `df` looks like this.

```
           id           location       type     price
0       44525        Golden Mile      House   4400000
1       44859           Nagüeles      House   2400000
2       45465           Nagüeles      House   1900000
3       50685           Nagüeles       Plot   4250000
4      130728        Golden Mile      House  32000000
5      130856           Nagüeles       Plot   2900000
6      130857        Golden Mile      House   3900000
7      130897        Golden Mile      House   3148000
8      3484102           Marinha       Plot    478000
9      3484124           Marinha       Plot   2200000
10     3485461           Marinha      House   1980000
```

So now,I have to find which property is undervalued or overvalued and which one has the genuine price on the basis of columns `location` and `type`. The desired  result should look like this:

```
       id           location       type     price   Over_val   Under_val    Norm_val
0   44525        Golden Mile      House   4400000         0      0             1
1   44859           Nagüeles      House   2400000         0      0             1
2   45465           Nagüeles      House   1900000         0      0             1
3   50685           Nagüeles       Plot   4250000         0      1             0
4  130728        Golden Mile      House  32000000         1      0             0
5  130856           Nagüeles       Plot   2900000         0      1             0
6  130857        Golden Mile      House   3900000         0      0             1
7  130897        Golden Mile      House   3148000         0      0             1
8  3484102           Marinha       Plot    478000         0      0             1
9  3484124           Marinha       Plot   2200000         0      0             1
10 3485461           Marinha      House   1980000         0      1             0
```

Have been stuck on it for a while. What logic should I try in solving this problem?

Comment: first remove the outlier then using quantile  qcut.

Comment: What determines if over or undervalued?

Comment: what does the quantile do? @Wen-Ben

Comment: To get a list of place and property  which is an ideal option for investment. @Kyle

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.qcut.html

Comment: I meant, what math would you use to determine if over or under? Greater than 2 stddev from the mean, or ???

Comment: yeah I'm using 2 stddev . @Kyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution. Explanation included as inline comments. There are probably ways to do this in lesser number of steps; I'll be interested to learn too.

```
import pandas as pd

# Replace this with whatever you have to load your data. This is set up for a sample data file I used
df = pd.read_csv('my_sample_data.csv', encoding='latin-1')

# Mean by location - type
mdf = df.set_index('id').groupby(['location','type'])['price'].mean().rename('mean').to_frame().reset_index()
# StdDev by location - type
sdf = df.set_index('id').groupby(['location','type'])['price'].std().rename('sd').to_frame().reset_index()
# Merge back into the original dataframe
df = df.set_index(['location','type']).join(mdf.set_index(['location','type'])).reset_index()
df = df.set_index(['location','type']).join(sdf.set_index(['location','type'])).reset_index()

# Add the indicator columns
df['Over_val'] = 0
df['Under_val'] = 0
df['Normal_val'] = 0

# Update the indicators
df.loc[df['price'] > df['mean'] + 2 * df['sd'], 'Over_val'] = 1
df.loc[df['price'] < df['mean'] - 2 * df['sd'], 'Under_val'] = 1

df['Normal_val'] = df['Over_val'] + df['Under_val']
df['Normal_val'] = df['Normal_val'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible method. At 2 standard deviations there are no qualifying properties. There is one property at one std dev.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={}, columns=["id", "location", "type", "price"])

# data is already entered, left out for this example
df["id"] = prop_id
df["location"] = location
df["type"] = prop_type
df["price"] = price

# a function that returns the mean and standard deviation
def mean_std_dev(row):
    mask1 = df["location"] == row["location"]
    mask2 = df["type"] == row["type"]
    df_filt = df[mask1 & mask2]
    mean_price = df_filt["price"].mean()
    std_dev_price = df_filt["price"].std()

    return [mean_price, std_dev_price]


# create two columns and populate with the mean and std dev from function mean_std_dev
df[["mean", "standard deviation"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series(mean_std_dev(row)), axis=1
)

# create final columns
df["Over_val"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x["price"] > x["mean"] + x["standard deviation"] else 0, axis=1
)
df["Under_val"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x["price"] < x["mean"] - x["standard deviation"] else 0, axis=1
)
df["Norm_val"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x["Over_val"] + x["Under_val"] == 0 else 0, axis=1
)

# delete the mean and standard deviation columns
df.drop(["mean", "standard deviation"], axis=1)
```